# How to use msoPattern constants to apply a pattern to a series in an Excel chart using Perl Win32::OLE

Tags: perl, excel, design-patterns, ole

I am using the Win32::OLE Perl module to change the pattern for a particular data point in a chart.

I can do this using:

```
$chart->SeriesCollection(2)->Points(5)->{Interior}->{Pattern} = xlPatternUp;
```

for example. To be clear this works exactly as expected.
However the xlPattern* constants only allow for a subset of the patterns Excel recognizes. It appears the full set of patterns is specified in the msoPattern* constants (at least the particular one I want to use is).

I tried to use one of the msoPattern* constants in the same manner:

```
$chart->SeriesCollection(2)->Points(5)->{Interior}->{Pattern} =
msoPatternWideUpwardDiagonal;
```

But this has no effect. The data point will render with a "solid" (default) pattern.
I have confirmed that I am importing the constants correctly, e.g.:

```
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library';
```

How can I use the msoPattern* constants to change the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The msoPatterns can be changed via the `Patterned` method of `{Format}->{Fill}` property.

e.g.

```
$chart->SeriesCollection(2)->Points(5)-
{Format}->Fill}->Patterned(msoPatternWideUpwardDiagonal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can do what you are trying to do.

If you take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224995 in the section *"Pattern property as it applies to the Interior object"* you'll find a list of all valid options.  And unfortunately only [xlPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlpattern) is valid.